# LinkedIn user's profile picture URL returns 403 - Forbidden or Access Denied, received over LinkedIn's OAuth 2.0 Developer API

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm currently making a LinkedIn app using the LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 Developer API with permissions `r_liteprofile` & `r_emailaddress` (Products added to my app include `Share on LinkedIn` & `Sign In with LinkedIn`).

Recently the profile images retrieved with this GET API (as per LinkedIn's own Developer documentation):

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,localizedFirstName,localizedLastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))
```

Have started to return either `403 - Forbidden`.

Full error message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>403 - Forbidden</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>403 - Forbidden</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**OR**

The error `Access Denied` e.g.

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E03AQHE3A16fLv1kQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0?" on this server.
Reference #18.2e5c7a5c.1589838983.25cfca02
```

E.g. https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E03AQHE3A16fLv1kQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0?e=1586995200&v=beta&t=zVNycwFPGiCoLZBJBkJoN6d_n7EAVVne-nK-r75RzMo

This URL gives me `Access Denied` when not using a VPN, and `403 - Forbidden` when using a VPN.

This tells me my IP address is being logged and some security mechanism kicking in if I access the URL directly a few times.

However about two months ago, I could directly link to this profile image URL from my app and it would load just fine.

If LinkedIn has made some changes and I can no longer link to the profile image URL - how else can I access the user's profile image?

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Check the `identifierExpiresInSeconds` of your identifier. You can see the field in the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/profile-picture#profile-api-sample-response

I created a Linkedin app to test this, and it works just fine for me. I can access the profile picture from different IPs, too. The response I am getting has an `identifierExpiresInSeconds` of `1596067200`, which is in exactly two months from the time of request.

That matches with your description of the issue - it worked fine two months ago. Now your identifier seems to have expired. You will need to perform another API call to get a valid picture identifier.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz this seems very logical. I have yet to test this is the case but I shall award you the bounty in the meantime and update this question once I have my application working again.